# Is there an openTBS command to write/update the Notes section of a pptx slide?

Tags: powerpoint, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using openTBS to update a slide deck and need to also update/replace template content in the Notes section. Is there a command that supports that?

Answer (score 0):

There is not native command for doing this but there is work around.

In a PPTX, comments are stored into sub XLM files such as `ppt/comments/comment2.xml`.
Each slide may have its own Comment sub-file.

I’s a bit complicated to find which Comment file is corresponding to what slide.
But you can find all Comment files in the PPTX using a code like this :

```
$all = $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_GET_FILES);
$comments = array();
foreach ($all as $file) {
    if (substr($file, 0, 13) == 'ppt/comments/') {
        $comments[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Then you can open each sub-file and merge data as an XML file.

```
foreach ($comments as $file) {
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, $file);
    $TBS->MergeFields(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response!